# how to compute the effectiveness of a treatment via statistical testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Statistical testing allows me to determine whether a treatment is statistically viable by measuring the responses of both the control and experimental groups.

In general, how to I answer the question: "How much better"? I know that using a statistical test can only tell me which one is better.

Comment: What do you mean by "statistically viable"?  As far as the question goes, have you investigated [estimation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation)?

Comment: Actually, I may be confused there. Estimation theory focuses on estimating the parameters for some distribution. Are you saying that I apply an estimation technique for the increase? I'd love to hear a toy example to concreitfy my understanding.

Comment: Consider, then, an unpaired Student t test.  The difference in sample means--which estimates the true difference in population means--answers "how much greater."  The standard error of that difference informs us about our confidence in that estimate.  That standard error, suitably normalized, is compared to a Student t distribution to identify whether one mean is greater than the other.  In your researches, you might want to focus on materials about statistical procedures that mention both "effect size" and "p-value".

Comment: There is uncertainity associated with each of the distributions modelled from an estimation theory perspective. If I use estimation theory to model two distributions, could I then compute a resulting "difference distribution"?

Comment: I would also like a percentage in increase - like a ratio: This is better by X% compared to without using the treatment,.

Comment: "How much better" is a question about measuring an effect size (in some sense). "Effectiveness of a statistical test" doesn't relate to that; a test would be "effective" if it gave good power for some reasonably low significance level. Do you mean to ask "how to compute the effectiveness of a treatment"?

Comment: Yes - that is what i eant